# How to automatically calculate the norm for users in our time registration application?

Tags: design, architecture, requirements, architectural-patterns

I'm creating a time registration application for employees where they can register their hours.

I want to show the users their "norm" (not sure if this is an actual word or just made up by my company). The norm is basically the number of hours someone has to work in a week.

For each week in a year, I have to show this "norm".

When someone has a 38 hours contract their norm for a normal week would be 38. Someone with 32 hours has a norm of 32. etc. etc.

Administrators can register "closed days", this means the company is closed for a specific day (national day off or whatever). This closed day counts for all users. As an example, let’s say this closed day is at week 30 on a Monday and the user has a 38 hours contract.

The norm in week 30 should be 30.4 for this user. Since the user works 5 days in a week, 38 / 5 = 7.6 and 38 - 7.6 = 30.4.

In reality the user works 8 hours a day instead of 7.6, meaning that they bill +2 hours a week as extra hours, in case they need a day off without using it’s holiday hours (regardless of whether that is a good practice or not). This means the user would work 32 hours this week (+1.6). This is good.

If employees (users) always work 5 days a week, no matter how many contract hours, calculating the norm would be easy. Just do the contract hours / 5 and subtract that from the contract hours, like I did above, and your done.

But here comes the problem.

Let’s say an employee has a 32 hours contract and is always free on Wednesday, working 4 days. What will now be the norm if on Monday the business is closed?

Now I know the answer is 24, but how does my system know this? Because what happens if the closed day is on Wednesday? Then the hours should be 32. For the system to know this he needs to know on which day people are free and how many hours they work each day. But this data will vary often and therefore makes maintaining it a lot of work.

Currently I just made the system always write the norm the same as the contract hours and added that administrators are able to change the norm for each week. Currently we have around 40 employee's using the time registration and about 6 closed days each year. Which means that each year we have to change the norm for 40 people 6 times. This takes less time than the above solution, but it still is time-consuming which I would like to automate.

**Is there a way to do this automatically or make it less time-consuming?**

Extra example, what if a user works like this:

Contract hours: 16

- Mon: 4 hours | Normally 4, but today is free since it’s a closed day.
- Tue: 4 hours
- Wed: free
- Thu: 6 hours
- Fri: 2 hours

It’s really hard to tell what the norm should be now. I know it’s 12, but how does the system know, without doing a lot of handwork for each employee?

I want it to be as automated as possible, but I'm not sure if this is actually possible.

**My idea of a solution is that it has something to do with different calculations. Right now to calculate we manually do: (contract hours / days you work a week = A, contract hours - A = norm), maybe there could be an entirely different calculation that does not depend on a variable thing like work days. Something more static.**

---

**PS:** I asked this question as a result of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370763/where-can-i-ask-about-a-problem-with-software-automation).

Comment: Are you aware this might be a legal question (depending on the jurisdiction of your company)? You cannot let the program "just calculate something which is easy to calculate". You need to find out what the right, legal rules are for part-time work.

Comment: Your description of what you calculate currently does not look like a valid formula. You're mixing `contract hours` and `days you work a week` which have different units. In addition, the `contract hours` in your two equations cancel each other out, so you get `days you work a week = norm`.

Comment: What do you need `contract_hours` for, then? If it's not relevant for the result you don't need to input it into the calculation. And I think `norm` is expressed in hours, while `days you work in a week` would be a number of days, right? Then `days you work a week` cannot possibly be equal to `norm`. Please get a waterproof definition of what you are supposed to calculate, the actual coding will be very simple then.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner Sorry I read it incorrect. It does not equal each other indeed. I dont know why you think im trying to calculate it like that. I just do the `contract hours / days you work in a week` to get the norm of the whole week. It works fine as long as I calculate it manually. Your answer also needs contract hours. I dont understand what your question is. Why do you think we dont need contract hours? Without it we can't calculate anything. Each employee has different contract hours.

Comment: Because the formulas that you wrote say so: `contract hours - days you work a week = A` and `contract hours - A = norm` can be combined to `contract hours - (contract hours - days you work a week) = norm` which is the same as `days you work a week = norm` using standard math conventions.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner Ahh, nooo. I wrote: `The norm in week 30 should be 30.4 for this user. Since the user works 5 days in a week, 38 / 5 = 7.6 and 38 - 7.6 = 30.4` where the slash in `38 / 5` means deviding not substracting. The norm means like the amount of hours a user has to work **in total** within a week. Which is based on his contract hours.

Comment: I copied verbatim from your last paragraph ("My idea of a solution ..."). But this is already too much of a discussion, which does not fit this format. There have been a number of specific suggestions (especially the one checking with the legal experts on what can be done).

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner I don't see a discussion. Just miscommunication. Which we just cleared up right? Besides, I dont know why someone downvoted. I think it's pretty clear what im asking. Your answer for example seems pretty much spot on.

Comment: `For the system to know this he needs to know on which day people are free and how many hours they work each day. But this data will vary often and therefore makes maintaining it a lot of work.` It's obvious you need a calendar and people activity reports. And of course, it won't be done by magic. Magic is incompatible with software engineering.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this sounds like a set of complicated and possibly inconsistent business rules, it's hard to implement such rules in software. The only thing you can be certain of is that someone's interpretation of the rules will not match yours.

So the first step (the task of a business analyst) is to determine what the actual rules should be. This may require working with the stakeholders to achieve a common understanding.

Of course it would be best if the common understanding is something that's easy to grasp, consistent, and implementable with a straightforward algorithm.

An easy and arguably fair approach would be to simply use `contractHours * (5 - freeDays) / 5` as the norm for each week. Don't take into account on which days someone works how many hours, or how many overtime hours they work, this only complicates matters and may make the calculation unfair.

Depending on the actual hours worked, workers will have a positive or negative difference between that and their norm. Business must define how much of this can be accumulated, how much "undertime" is permitted, how much counts as paid overtime, how much can be exchanged into additional free days without consuming contractual holidays, etc.

Your approach of calculating a norm of 12 hours in your last example seems to imply that as the employee would work 4 hours on Monday, and Monday is the closed day, her norm is reduced by 4 hours. What about an employee with the same number of hours but who works 4 hours on Wednesday and none on Monday? Will they have a norm of 16 hours? Sounds not fair at all.

In the simplified scheme, each of those workers (the one from your example, and the hypothetical free-on-Monday worker) have 16 hours/week contractual time. Due to the closed day (regardless of which weekday it is) their norm for that week should be 16*0.8 = 12.8 hours. This means your example worker either must work a little longer on one day this week, or take over the difference into the next week and work a little longer then. The hypothetical free-Monday worker will enjoy a having a shorter work week, but overall both will have the same 12.8 hour norm.

The nice thing about such a scheme is that it makes the whole software much simpler to implement and easier to verify for correctness, because the rules are clear and can be checked easily.

Comment: Why do you think it's not fair? If you never worked on monday and the company now is closed aswell on monday then nothing changes for you right? Why should that mean that you can work less in that week? Your calculation is great tho! I think this might actually be it :D. I wish I could also make it fair in the sense that you don't end up with a positive or negative amount of hours between their norm. But I agree that this makes things too complicated. Atleast if you want to implement it in software.

Comment: Of course you're right that the notion of fairness is subjective. One person might prefer the "uncut" work and pay opportunity, another might prefer having to work a bit less in a week where the company is closed on one day even though that is their free day anyway. That's why my naive solution may be overly simplistic, and a BA should analyze the needs of your organization and its workers. The main point is that you should strive for clearness and keeping things as simple as possible.

Comment: *"So the first step (the task of a business analyst) is to determine what the actual rules should be. This may require working with the stakeholders to achieve a common understanding."* - I think it is more likely the BA has to ask a specialist in employment law, maybe a lawyer.

Comment: @DocBrown That, too.

Comment: @DocBrown We do not really have a BA though. Our company isn't that big (around 40 employees). We use a CAO where these rules can be found I think. Wouldn't be this complicated right? But maybe im oversimplifying.

Comment: @Allart: take BA as a synonym for "whoever does the analysis of your business requirements". But I am sure there are either contractual and/or legal issues to take into account. If your program calculates something which is not in accordance with the working contract of your part-time workers or the employment laws of your country, I am sure you get in trouble.